# How to properly analyze: 4-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, likert, minitab

I have a dissertation research question which involves what I am thinking is appropriately analyzed using 4-way ANOVA. The dependent variable is a math anxiety score (uses 5-point Likert scale). The independent variables, for this portion of the analysis, include categories: math/statistics and accounting/finance with criteria of failure (need to or did repeat course) and success (course grade of ‘C or better’ with or without first needing to repeat) for each.

---

I am thinking this is a four-way ANOVA using two levels for each factor:
Math/Stats-Repeat: Yes or no
ACC/FIN-Repeat: Yes or no
Math/Stats-Success: Yes or no
ACC/FIN-Success: Yes or no

---

Null hypothesis: There are no significant main effects due to failure or success in barrier courses (4 factors with 2 levels each: Repeat math or statistics (yes or no); Repeat accounting or finance (yes or no); Success math or statistics (yes or no); Success accounting or finance (yes or no)).
Are there any significant interaction effects among barrier course experience factors? Null hypothesis: There are no significant interaction effects due to failure or success in barrier courses.

---

I submitted this note to my mentor about my thinking for this…Note on expected findings: Students who express they need to repeat math (for example) but have not yet repeated it might have an unusually high mathematics anxiety score which could show up as a significant interaction effect between repeat MAT/STAT and passing MAT/STAT.

---

Am I overcomplicating this situation, or should this really be handled in this manner? I am concerned collapsing will miss potential interactions. Also, will Minitab be a good tool for this analysis? I anticipate several hundred participants and unbalanced data.

Comment: You describe a complex undertaking with no simple answer. As a student, you may have access to some free help from the statistics department in your school.  You might stop by the department and ask the secretary whom to talk with, or ask to speak w the department chair. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I have asked two Statistics professors and will keep working.